# Double quotes with monospaced font and LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, punctuation, typewriter

I am trying to set the following minimal document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>An Example of a Web page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is an example of a Web page</p>
</body>
</html>
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

I would like to keep the HTML text as it exists in the file and use the verbatim environment for that.

I want symmetrical typewriter double quotes rather than the typographic right/left paired double quotes.

I get the latter rather than the former when I compile the above file with lualatex.

How might I get what I want?

=== Addendum 1 ===

I downloaded the font from the blog post link suggested by Khaled Hosny below, unzipped it, and installed it on my Linux system as a system font.

`fc-list | grep Inconsolata` shows the font as 'Inconsolata-dz:style=dz'.

I then changed the single line with Inconsolata to Inconsolata-dz in the file above.

When I tried compiling with lualatex, it terminates prematurely with these lines:

```
luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
luaotfload | Scanning TEXMF fonts...
luaotfload | Scanning OS fonts...
! Font \zf@basefont=name:Inconsolata-dz at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop: 
l.3 \setmonofont{Inconsolata-dz}
```

Comment: You do know that the shape you see is what is in Inconsolata, yes? See http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html

Comment: In reply to Addendum 1: I installed the font in `~/.fonts` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I'm getting here is the ASCII double quote, but it is drawn curly not straight in the font, and that is a known (mis)feature of Inconsolata, check this [blog post](http://nodnod.net/2009/feb/12/adding-straight-single-and-double-quotes-inconsola/) for a modified version with straight quotes.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I was not aware of the (mis)feature of this font and even less aware of the workaround. My problem has been solved now.

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation of how to use your fix to use your modified version of inconsolata in a document. Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded the font from the blog post link, unzipped it, and installed it on my Linux system as a system font.

Comment: Please see addendum in my Original post on problems encountered with using Inconsolata-dz. Grateful for pointers.

Comment: @chandra: I already replied above; this usually means the font is not seen by luaotfload, but the installation went fine on my side.