# Single quotes in double quotes

Tags: editors, punctuation, texniccenter

I want to write "''" (to denote the empty string). However in LaTeX, when I try to enter `"''"`, TexnicCenter replaces it with ``` ``'''' ``` , which displays as “”” (first pointing left, second two pointing right).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this first [How to get straight quotation marks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/how-to-get-straight-quotation-marks/7738#7738). And the following is how to setup your TeXnicCenter.

### Step 1

Select `Tools` menu item.

[image]

### Step 2

Select `Options...`

[image]

### Step 3

Select `Custom` and fill each textbox with `"` only.

[image]

### Step 4

Mark this answer with a green check mark. :-)

Comment: Couldn't you just uncheck “Replace quotation marks”?

Comment: In Step 4, I should inform it explicitly.