# Straight quote literals when using LuaTeX and fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec

This is a similar question to [How to get straight quotation marks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/how-to-get-straight-quotation-marks), but in my case, I want literal ' and " marks to stay that way, as I use Unicode curly quotes when I want curly quotes. Is there a simple header option to make this happen? I’m using LuaTeX and `fontspec`.

(Background: I’m using Emacs to export existing Org documents—written, not by me, with straight quotes only—as PDFs. When I did this with the default PDFLaTeX setup, Unicode special characters (not quotes, but other special characters) wouldn’t render. So I changed the compiler to LuaTeX and found a way to add `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` to my documents’ header options, and now Unicode special characters work, but every straight quote is rendered as a closing curly quote. This is simply too much for my autistic sensibilities!)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "smart" closing single and double quotes are generated if `fontspec`'s option `Ligatures=TeX` option is active, which is the case by default. To switch it off, just specify the option `Ligatures=TeXOff` -- or, equivalently, `[RawFeature=-tlig]` -- when running `\setmainfont` or `\setsansfont`. Observe that this approach works with all fonts, not just `Linux Libertine O`.

Note that setting `Ligatures=TeXOff` will also prevent `--` and `---` being converted automatically to en-dashes and em-dashes, respectively. Please advise if this might cause a problem for your document. (Given that your document already Unicode curly quotes, I tend to think that it might also use Unicode en- and em-dash characters; however, I may be wrong.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand\dummysentence{A sentence with straight 'single' and  "double" quotes.}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[Ligatures=TeXOff] % or [RawFeature=-tlig]
\dummysentence

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[Ligatures=TeXOff,
                          Scale=MatchLowercase % same x-height as preceding font
                         ]
\dummysentence 

\setsansfont{Helvetica Neue}[Ligatures=TeXOff,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\textsf{\dummysentence}

\setsansfont{Myriad Pro Cond}[Ligatures=TeXOff,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\textsf{\dummysentence}
\end{document}
```

`

Comment: Do you have a reference for this TeXOff syntax?  It's not in the fontspec manual as far as I can tell and I get *Key 'fontspec-opentype/Ligatures' accepts only a fixed set of choices*

Comment: @Clément - I can only point to section 3.1.8, "Ligatures", of the `fontspec` manual, along with associated table 11. Version 2.7i of the package, dated 2020/02/21, is used with MacTeX2020 and MacTeX2021. Which version of the package is on your system?

Comment: Version 2.7h of 2020/02/03; thanks, with the pointer in the manual I found the reference.  Using the RawFeature form works.